# How to run .sh file from res folder in java project on linux?

Tags: java, shell

I can access the image from res folder in java project with this code.

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/Images/main.jpg");
```

But , How can I run .sh file from res folder in java project on linux?

Give a solution for this ?

Comment: Sounds sketchy, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to run the .sh file from project's res folder on linux os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Runtime.exec()`

```
public static void excuteCommand(String filePath) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if(!file.isFile()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The file " + filePath + " does not exist");
    }
    if(isLinux()){
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", filePath}, null);
    }else if(isWindows()){
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + filePath);
    }
}

public static boolean isLinux(){
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");  
    return os.toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") >= 0;
}

public static boolean isWindows(){
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    return os.toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") >= 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pradeep call excuteCommand with your .sh file path and it will run it

Comment: @Pradeep ex. you put your .sh file in /image/mysh.sh, then you call excuteCommand("/image/mysh.sh")

Comment: Can I run the .sh file on both linux and windows?

Comment: @Pradeep you can, this code will call cmd in windows to run your .sh and it will call sh in linux to run your .sh, just make sure of your file Path.